# WordPress SEARCH function working only on Home Page

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I'm trying to figure out how to add more pages(?) into this search function so that it can work on pages besides the home page. Here is the code, currently in functions.php within the frameworks folder of a theme I'm using.

```
function themize_html5_search_form( $form ) {
  $form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
  <input type="text" placeholder="'.__("Search").'" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" />
  <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
  </form>';
return $form;
}
add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'themize_html5_search_form' );
```

I'm wondering if it's the $_GET which is not returning a value? When I look into functions.php this is what I see, doesn't seem like it's related to search, but I'm not sure.

```
 (isset($_GET['paged']) && !empty($_GET['paged'])) {echo "<li>Blog Archives"; echo'</li>';
```

Just to clarify, on the Home page of the url, let's say example.com and if I search the results will come back example.com/?s=searchedItem
But on a different page, let's say About, the url will be example.com/about?s=searchedItem and then I'll get nothing back, even though I'm searching the exact same keyword.

Comment: `action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '"` will submit to the home page , `action=""` will submit to current page. `$_GET['paged']` will look for a variable called paged

Comment: @David so would separating the action fix the error then. Something like this. 

         `<form action="/" method="get">
 <label for="search">Search in <?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?></label>
 <input type="text" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" />
 <input type="image" alt="Search" src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/search.png" />
</form>`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure myself still what you are desiring?

Do you care if all search bars, regardless of starting page, puts you at `example.com/?s=query` with generic results for query?

Or are you wanting the keep them on the page they performed the search? If so, what is your desired output?

Comment: @Practically I want to be able to search from anywhere on the site and be able to get a list of results. Currently, the search only works on the Home Page.

Comment: ah now i get you, you will need to find the code that deals with the search query string, it will either be using `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST` or `get_query_vars()` or similar but until you find the code that deals with it and find out what is happening on the other pages it is impossible for someone to answer.